# Only classes can set 'stage'; normal resources like XXX cannot change run stage

Tags: puppet

I have a manifest where a package depends on an `apt::source` resource.  I've tried to make sure the `apt::source` runs first by setting a stage:

```
include apt

stage { 'first': 
    before => Stage['main']
}

apt::source { 'erlang_repo':
  location => 'http://packages.erlang-solutions.com/ubuntu',
  repos    => 'contrib',
  key      => 'A14F4FCA',
  stage    => first
}

package { 'erlang':
  ensure   => '1:17.3'
}
```

However, I'm hitting the following error:

```
==> default: Error: Puppet::Parser::AST::Resource failed with error ArgumentError: Only classes can set 'stage'; normal resources like Apt::Source[erlang_repo] cannot change run stage at /tmp/manifests/default.pp:12 on node vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64.home
==> default: Wrapped exception:
==> default: Only classes can set 'stage'; normal resources like Apt::Source[erlang_repo] cannot change run stage
==> default: Error: Puppet::Parser::AST::Resource failed with error ArgumentError: Only classes can set 'stage'; normal resources like Apt::Source[erlang_repo] cannot change run stage at /tmp/manifests/default.pp:12 on node vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64.home
```

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *really* want to use stages, you should wrap the appropriate resources in (possibly dedicated) classes.

```
class site::apt_sources {
    apt::source { ... }
}
```

and declare it like

```
class { 'site::apt_sources': stage => first }
```

Please note that the use of stages is discouraged.

If you don't use virtual resources, you can probably achieve the desired effect through this relationship instead:

```
Apt::Source<| |> -> Package<| |>
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go with this in the end:

```
include apt

Apt::Pin <| |> -> Package <| |>
Apt::Source <| |> -> Package <| |>

apt::source { 'erlang_repo':
  location => 'http://packages.erlang-solutions.com/ubuntu',
  repos    => 'contrib',
  key      => 'A14F4FCA'
}

package { 'erlang':
  ensure   => '1:17.3',
}
```